# How to sort a list of dictionaries based on the value of one certain key without using sort() in Python

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, key

I am trying to sort a large json file with Steam games in descending order based on the value of key: positive_ratings, without using the built in sort() function.

```
small_example = [
{'id':10,'game':'Counterstrike','positive_ratings':150},
{'id':20,'game':'Bioshock Infinite','positive_ratings':50},
{'id':30,'game':'Rust','positive_ratings':300},
{'id':40,'game':'Portal','positive_ratings':200}
]
```

The output in descending order would be the following list:
`['Rust', 'Portal', 'Counterstrike', 'Bioshock Infinite']`

For school we had to make a quick sort function that sorts lists like below. Now i would like to rewrite it so it sorts a list of dictionaries.

```
def quick_sort(sequence):
    length = len(sequence)
    if length <= 1:
        return sequence
    else:
        centre = sequence.pop()


    items_bigger = []
    items_smaller = []

    for item in sequence:
        if item > centre:
            items_bigger.append(item)

        else: items_smaller.append(item)

    return quick_sort(items_smaller) + [centre] + quick_sort(items_bigger)


print(quick_sort([1,2,5,6,2,10,34,54,23,1]))
```

Comment: use `sorted()` if `.sort()` is not allowed? But I guess that won't be allowed too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you sort the list based on the element's value. But what you want is sorting list based on `element['positive_ratings']`. You just need to alter code a little bit:

```
def quick_sort(sequence):
    length = len(sequence)
    if length <= 1:
        return sequence
    else:
        centre = sequence.pop()


    items_bigger = []
    items_smaller = []

    for item in sequence:
        if item['positive_ratings'] > centre['positive_ratings']: # I changed only this line
            items_bigger.append(item) 

        else: items_smaller.append(item)

    return quick_sort(items_smaller) + [centre] + quick_sort(items_bigger)
```

`sort` function also works like that, you just specify the key:

```
some_list.sort(key= lambda x: x['positive_ratings'])
```

We can adjust your code to look similar to `sort` function:

```
def quick_sort(sequence, key = lambda x: x):
    length = len(sequence)
    if length <= 1:
        return sequence
    else:
        centre = sequence.pop()


    items_bigger = []
    items_smaller = []

    for item in sequence:
        if key(item> key(centre): # I changed only this line
            items_bigger.append(item) 

        else: items_smaller.append(item)

    return quick_sort(items_smaller, key) + [centre] + quick_sort(items_bigger, key)
```

You can call it like this:

```
quick_sort(small_example, key = lambda x: x['positive_ratings'])
```

Edit: I forgot to add key in the last line. Thanks to @DarrylG I fixed that

Comment: I upvoted your answer before noticing you have an error in your code that prevents it from working.  Version with key should be:  `return quick_sort(items_smaller, key) + [centre] + quick_sort(items_bigger, key)

Answer (score 0):

you can sort the example, by sorting the data based, based on the key `positive_ratings` ie sort the postive_ratings values first and then based on that return the output

```
small_example = [
{'id':10,'game':'Counterstrike','positive_ratings':150},
{'id':20,'game':'Bioshock Infinite','positive_ratings':50},
{'id':30,'game':'Rust','positive_ratings':300},
{'id':40,'game':'Portal','positive_ratings':200}
]



def func(data, key: int):
    dic = {}
    for i in data:
        if i[key] not in dic:
            dic[i[key]] = [i]
        else:
            dic[i[key]].append(i)
    
    dic_key = list(dic.keys())
    
    # sorting the dic_key, sorting data based on postive_raing values, you can
    # use any sort algo here
    
    for i in range(len(dic_key)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(dic_key)):
            if dic_key[i]>dic_key[j]:
                dic_key[i], dic_key[j] = dic_key[j], dic_key[i]
    
    result = []
    for i in dic_key:
        result.extend(dic[i])
    return result

sol =  func(small_example, 'positive_ratings')
print(solution)
```

output

```
[{'id': 20, 'game': 'Bioshock Infinite', 'positive_ratings': 50},
 {'id': 10, 'game': 'Counterstrike', 'positive_ratings': 150},
 {'id': 40, 'game': 'Portal', 'positive_ratings': 200},
 {'id': 30, 'game': 'Rust', 'positive_ratings': 300}]
```